# Has Ant-Man ever passed through Captain America’s shield?

Tags: marvel, captain-america, ant-man

Captain America's shield has been broken by godly powers. It’s also withstood impressive beatings by Hulk and Thor, etc. It has great abilities in helping deflect kinetic energy, but these tests don't include the quantum aspect that Ant-Man has.

This article:

- http://nerdist.com/the-science-of-small-how-does-the-ant-man-suit-work/

talks about Ant-Man’s density becoming that of a white dwarf. The compactness changes things: quantum particles can pass through matter without issues.

So: has Ant-Man ever become small enough to pass through Captain America’s shield? And if so, is there *any* material that can stop him?

Comment: It would probably help if you quantified the specific fictional universe you are talking about.  Cinematic?  Comics?  Etc.; they don't tend to follow the same rules, in many cases.  My guess would be Marvel Cinematic universe, based on the Ant-Man movie and the Avengers: Civil War, but specifics would help your question.

Comment: @K-H-W, I'm unfamiliar with the impact the universes would have, so if someone is able to answer for what they know, that would be awesome. If it differs then that would help make a better answer pointing out the differences

Comment: I think we can be fairly confident that Ant-Man has never punched through Captain America’s shield, in any universe.

Comment: This could possibly be closed as a duplicate of any of the other questions about how strong the shield is.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I'm not so sure, because there is a quantum affect that is implied. Capt's shield can be broke by godly powers... but can absorb kinetic energy well... question is what happens when you pull in the quantum affect that ant man can.

Comment: @venomfangs can you [edit] your post to include details about that? It's not something I knew about,  and might explain why this an important question that's worth asking/answering.

Comment: @VenomFangs: I think you’re imagining that there’s a nice consistent set of rules for both Ant-Man’s shrinking abilities, and Captain America’s shield. There isn’t. The MCU is not based on actual physics.