# Has Ant-Man ever penetrated vibranium or adamantium?

Tags: marvel, ant-man

This question was inspired by this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122950/has-ant-man-ever-jumped-at-captain-america-s-shield).  Have there been any examples of Ant-Man (or any other shrinkers) penetrating/permeating through any of the fictional metals in the Marvel universe?

Comment: More broadly: I don't remember seeing Ant-Man going _through_ any material whatsoever (although I'm not reading a lot of comics). He's mostly depicted going _into_ tiny cracks, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as the only Vibranium Ant-Man was in contact with would have been Cap's shield, Vision, or something in Wakanda (in the continuity of the MCU), it hasn't happened. However, it is possible seeing as Ant-Man can shrink smaller than any particle and thus enter the Quantum Realm. Adamantium does not exist in the MCU as of the last time we saw Ant-Man, although it is likely that other non-MCU Marvel properties could make an appearance in *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania*.

Comment: Ant-Man has also been in contact with Vision, who is made of vibranium, and in fact they were on opposite sides of a big superhero battle in _Civil War_ so it would have been quite plausible for that battle to include him penetrating Vision’s vibranium. Though I agree that it didn’t actually happen.

Comment: I don’t meant specifically the MCU, I’m referring to all Marvel properties.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not learned in the ways of the comics.